# Processing RAW audio data from Android

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiorecord, oboe

I’m struggling since days trying to obtain a raw audio stream from the microphone. I am trying different ways: the low-level JNI way with Oboe Library (either AAudio and OpenSL ES implementations) and the Android’s AudioRecord Java classes.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to retrieve amplitudes near -/+1.0 while being sure of saturating the microphone input with a calibrated pure tone with such a high amplitude.
I think that the problem is that I am not able to effectively disable the signal preprocessing from AndroidOS (Automatic Gain Control or Noise Cancelling).

```
AutomaticGainControl.create(id).setEnabled(false)
```

(not working!)

Also, it seems that it is not possible also to disable any additional microphone rather than the one "selected" (done that as selecting the `setPreferredDevice` on `AudioRecord` instance). Used as audio source: unprocessed, mic, voice_recognition.

Is there anyway doing this or am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Which audio source are you using for your recording? VOICE_RECOGNITION or UNPROCESSED are mandated to not have any pre-processing enabled by default (i.e. see https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd#5_11_capture_for_unprocessed) and therefore would allow you to check your signal path.